# Angular 2+ Using Variable over components (e.g. global)

Tags: angular, typescript, variables, components, global

In Angular 2+ I use a navigation component with a button and a click event like the following:

```
<button (click)="navlnk(about, $event)">About</button>
```

In the app.component.html I want to use the variable (here variable: about) from click event, like the following:

```
<article #about class="about active">
 lorem ipsum
</article>
```

Actually I have the following code in app.component.ts

```
navlnk(page: any, event: any) {
    page.classList.add('active'); // Show 'About' <article>
}
```

The code works fine, when all the code is placed in one component.

But how can I export the navigation to it's own component and call variable 'about' in main app.component.html ?

Can anybody help?

Comment: I am also interested in this topic.

Comment: Can't you use routing?

Comment: @rohithpoya Actually I really want to try it without routing, to keep the App as simple as possible. I do not want to implement all this router stuff and create for every view an own component.

Comment: Use eventemitter. Define eventemitter using @output decorator. Emit event from child to parent in this case to main component, and call function navlink

Comment: @rohithpoya I decided to use Routing now :-(